# Connecting passive monitors to sound card

Tags: amplifier, cards

I searched on Google, but didn't find the answere. I want to buy some external sound card (for example Yamaha AG03, but I would like to understand how this works in general) and some monitor speakers.

I saw that this card (and many other) do have a monitor output. Does this output have the power needed to drive passive monitors or should I need an external amplifier?

Comment: You most certainly need an amplifier. Passive speakers do not run without an amplifier.....

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I really don't get why this was closed. Other questions about that microphone brand is not working on that os version or using that sound card to record this stuff are still opened... but ok whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://download.yamaha.com/api/asset/file?language=en&site=countrysite-master.prod.wsys.yamaha.com&asset_id=64325)

-- the "Monitor outs" are line-level, therefore you will need an amplifier between the monitor outputs and your passive monitor-speakers.

Comment: (@Paolo) ...FYI Most studios use active monitors for various reasons. Most professional interfaces will have 6.3mm(1/4in) TRS(balllanced) line outputs with a +4dBu(professional) level.